# Apache Solr search by "AND"

Tags: solr

I am working on Apache Solr.

Currently, it is working fine. When I typed in `pork AND belly` it will return all queries with `pork` and `belly` in it.

But I need to search `pork and belly` and get the same result.

But it does not as it will return all results with `pork` or `and` or `belly`.

The easiest way is to change it in JavaScript before sending the query.

But is there a way to do it from Apache Solr by updating the `config`?

Thanks.

What I did: I tried to switch it in `schema.xml` by adding the `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory` at the `dynamic field`, but obviously it failed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eDisMax query parser accepts lower case operators by default. In your `solrconfig.xml`, specify that parser and you can also explicitly tell it to accept lower case operators:

```
<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="defType">edismax</str>
     <bool name="lowercaseOperators">true</bool>
   </lst>
   ...
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the (e)dismax query handler, just searching `pork belly` with `q.op=AND` should work fine. As long as you have a StopWordFilter configured for your set (and a proper dictionary), `and` will automagically removed. The default `stopwords_en.txt` file bundled with Solr has that in its list.